# Box2D: Setting more than one b2ContactListener to world? - Getting weird behavior

Tags: javascript, html, box2d

So I am very new to Box2D and I'm trying to figure out how to use b2ContactListener.

Are you allowed to set more than one Contact Listeners to a world? I would think so. But when set two contact listeners like so:

```
world.SetContactListener(listener);
world.SetContactListener(listener2);
```

It behaves like `listener2` was the only one set. Why is that? 
Also when I change the order of how I set the listeners like so:

```
world.SetContactListener(listener2);
world.SetContactListener(listener);
```

Then it behaves like `listener` was the only contact listener set and ignores `listener2`.

The only reason I think why this could be behaving like this is because both of the listeners override the `BeginContact` and `EndContact` methods so it's confused.

I am using the JavaScript port of Box2D (Box2DWeb) by the way. But if you know the solution to the issue in Objective-C or C++ that's fine as I know those languages.

Answer (score 3):

The hint is in the name - "Set" rather than "Add". It implies that there is only 1 listener supported. Update your listener class to dispatch to multiple methods if you need to.

It seems you are confused about what overriding methods entails. Having the same method overridden on multiple objects does not cause anything to get confused. The issue is that there is only one listener meant to be registered at once (because having a lot of listeners would slow things down - it will get called a lot)